# REBOL3 - How to set the initial size of a layout?

Tags: rebol, rebol3, r3-gui

I need to set the initial size of a layout to be viewed.  How do I do that?

in R2, it was:

```
view layout/size [button] 1000x1000
```

There is no longer a `size` refinement on layout and trying to set a facet does not work

```
view layout [button] options [facets: [size: 1000x1000]]
```

right now, `view/maximize` is a workaround for the bug for me, but would prefer not to use maximized windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create your face before and set the init-size manually as in

```
 b:  layout [button]
 b/facets/init-size: 300x80
 view b
```